# Arrow is not aligned

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, decorations, hobby

I am tryinf to make a multi-connected region in tikz. The arrow on the circle inside is weirdly tilted or angled somehow. as can be seen in the zoomed picture. I coloured them so that it can be seen easily. [image]

[image]

Here is what I want to achieve(something like this).

[image]

Look at the arrow on the circle they are nicely aligned. How to make to look like that.
Thank you. Here is the code

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usetikzlibrary{hobby}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
    markings,% switch on markings
    mark=at position .75 with {\arrow[line width=.02mm]{stealth}},
    }
    ]
    \path[gray!40, fill=gray!20,draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true,scale=.75]
                          (0,1) .. (1,3) .. (3,3) .. (4,2) .. (4.5,.5) .. (4,0) .. (3,.2) .. (1,0);
    \draw[postaction={decorate},fill=white] (1,1.2) circle (.2cm);
    \draw[postaction={decorate},fill=white] (2,1.2) circle (.2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

The New Code

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0.6pt,outer sep=0pt},node font=\tiny,
        every label/.append style={inner sep=0pt}]
    \path[gray!40, fill=gray!20,draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
                          (0,1.5) .. (1.5,3) .. (3,3) .. (5,2) .. (4.5,.5) .. (4,0) .. (3.2,.2) .. (1,0);
    \draw[postaction={draw,-{stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] (.5,1.5) + (-90:0.2)
    arc[start angle=-190,end angle=170,radius=0.3] node[above left]{$C_1$};
    \draw[postaction={draw,-{stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] (2,2.2) + (-90:0.2)
    arc[start angle=-90,end angle=280,radius=0.3]node[below]{$C_2$};;;
    \draw[postaction={draw,-{stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] (4,2) + (-90:0.2)
    arc[start angle=90,end angle=480,radius=0.3]node[above]{$C_3$};;;
    \draw[postaction={draw,-{stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] (2.3,.75) + (-90:0.2)
    arc[start angle=-10,end angle=350,radius=0.3] node[right]{$C_k$};;
    \path (.5,1.5) node[bullet,label=right:$a$]{} (2,2.2) node[bullet,label=right:$b$]{}
          (4,2) node[bullet,label=right:$a$]{} (2.3,.75) node[bullet,label=right:$b$]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add bent arrows via `postaction`. Straight arrows look IMHO never great on curves.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0.6pt,outer sep=0pt},node font=\tiny,
    every label/.append style={inner sep=0pt}]
\path[gray!40, fill=gray!20,draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true,scale=.75]
                      (0,1) .. (1,3) .. (3,3) .. (4,2) .. (4.5,.5) .. (4,0) .. (3,.2) .. (1,0);
\draw[postaction={draw,-{Stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] 
    (1,1.2) + (-90:0.2) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=280,radius=0.2];
\draw[postaction={draw,-{Stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] 
    (2,1.2) + (-90:0.2) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=280,radius=0.2];
\path   (1,1.2) node[bullet,label=right:$a$]{}
(2,1.2) node[bullet,label=right:$b$]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0.6pt,outer sep=0pt},node font=\tiny,
    every label/.append style={inner sep=0pt}]
\path[gray!40, fill=gray!20,draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
                      (0,1.5) .. (1.5,3) .. (3,3) .. (5,2) .. (4.5,.5) .. (4,0) .. (3.2,.2) .. (1,0);
\draw[postaction={draw,-{stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] 
(.5,1.5) + (-190:0.3) arc[start angle=-190,end angle=170,radius=0.3] node[above left]{$C_1$};
\draw[postaction={draw,-{stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] (2,2.2) + (-90:0.3)
arc[start angle=-90,end angle=280,radius=0.3]node[below]{$C_2$};
\draw[postaction={draw,-{stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] (4,2) + (90:0.3)
arc[start angle=90,end angle=480,radius=0.3]node[above]{$C_3$};
\draw[postaction={draw,-{stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white] (2.3,.75) + (-10:0.3)
arc[start angle=-10,end angle=350,radius=0.3] node[right]{$C_k$};
\path (.5,1.5) node[bullet,label=right:$a$]{} (2,2.2) node[bullet,label=right:$b$]{}
      (4,2) node[bullet,label=right:$a$]{} (2.3,.75) node[bullet,label=right:$b$]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can simplify things with a `pic`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0.6pt,outer sep=0pt},node font=\tiny,
    every label/.append style={inner sep=0pt},
    pics/pole/.style={code={
            \tikzset{pole pars/.cd,#1}%
            \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pole pars/##1}}%
            \draw[postaction={draw,-{stealth[bend,length=1mm]}},fill=white]
             (\pv{angle}-\pv{orientation}*20:\pv{radius}) 
             arc[start angle=\pv{angle}-\pv{orientation}*20,end
             angle=\pv{angle}+\pv{orientation}*360,radius=\pv{radius}];
    }},pole pars/.cd,radius/.initial=0.3,angle/.initial=-90,
    orientation/.initial=1,
    clockwise/.code={\tikzset{pole pars/orientation=-1}}]
\path[gray!40, fill=gray!20,draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
                      (0,1.5) .. (1.5,3) .. (3,3) .. (5,2) .. (4.5,.5) .. (4,0) .. (3.2,.2) .. (1,0);
\draw (.5,1.5) pic{pole={angle=160}} 
     node[bullet,label=right:$a$]{} ++(135:0.3)  node[above left]{$C_1$}
 (2,2.2) pic{pole={angle=-90}} node[bullet,label=right:$b$]{}
    ++(-90:0.3) node[below]{$C_2$}
 (4,2) pic{pole={angle=100}} node[bullet,label=right:$a$]{}
    ++(90:0.3) node[above]{$C_3$}
 (2.3,.75) pic{pole={angle=310}}  node[bullet,label=right:$b$]{}
 ++(00:0.3) node[right]{$C_k$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, I see these are not circles. Considering them as a circle how to I display their centres ? Like the one in the picture.?

Comment: @Kumarm These are circles, drawn as arcs in order to attach the arrow. The centers of the circles did not change. Please see the update for how to add the labeled bullets.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to keep bothering you. But its not exactly working for me as i needed. I have changed the radius and some stuff and centres are not as expected. You can see the updated code.

Comment: @Kumarm You cannot use different parameters for the offset and arc. See my next update.

Comment: Thank you. I did not get your last comment.